# How do I store SOAP responses in the database securely?

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, soap, spring-security

I am working on an internal tool that simulates SOAP responses for different web services that our product uses. This is intended for use in local development.

The idea is to store the SOAP responses in the database as a blob data. During the mapping of a URL keys to a response, the URL keys and expected SOAP response will be stored to the database. The simulated SOAP response will be as a string body in POST request.

The SOAP response will be stored as a blob in the database along with URL keys. If the URL is `/configureresponse/{responsetype}/{responsecode}/`, then the values of response type and response code will be saved to the database along with the SOAP response as string.

I am building a Spring MVC application for the same. The code snippet is given below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/configureresponse/{responsetype}/{responsecode}",
                method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView configureResponse(
        @PathVariable String responseType, @PathVariable String responseCode,
        @RequestBody String soapResponse) {

}
```

1. How do I return a Servlet Response such as 200 OK or 403 Forbidden based on certain conditions?
2. Is there a way to secure the incoming XML response and the outgoing XML response? This is an internal tool, but I am not sure how to handle XML injection or any other security issues.

**UPDATE**: How do I secure the application against a billion laughs attack or make it more secure?

3. Should I be checking for XSRF vulnerability? If yes, how do I do that?
4. How do I handle simultaneous concurrent inputs for the same response and request?

**UPDATE**: How do I check if say one thread is updating the response for a given response type and response code, while the other thread is viewing the response for a given response type and response code?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How do I return a Servlet Response such as 200 OK or 403 Forbidden based on certain conditions?

There are several ways to do this.  For instance, you could change your return type to a `ResponseEntity<String>`, which has a constructor that accepts an `HttpStatus`.  Or, you could simply pass in an HttpServletResponse and set the response code there.  Knowing Spring, there are probably 20 more valid ways to do this.  I would suggest reading through the excellent Reference Guide available on their site.

> 1. Is there a way to secure the incoming XML response and the outgoing XML response? This is an internal tool, but I am not sure how to handle XML injection or any other security issues.

Not sure what you mean by "secure".  If you mean transmission, then use SSL.  If you mean authorization/authentication use Spring Security.  If you mean something else, then I am not sure what to offer except to say I need a better explanation of what you want/need.

> 1. Should I be checking for XSRF vulnerability? If yes, how do I do that? Any link or tutorial would be welcome.

Security should be a concern, whether it's an internal app or external.  Most hacks now-a-days are done by social engineering their way into the intra-net of a company.  Take the recent Target breach.  I believe they used the AC repair service to gain access to the building.  I went to a Schmoocon talk once where a guy hired to test a companies' security actually got a job as a janitor and would plug in a Linux device he built, go mop some floors, then pick up the device which had scanned all their internal networks.  So, yes, if you believe you should guard against an attack, then I would say do so.

> 1. How do I handle simultaneous concurrent inputs for the same response and request?

Not sure what you mean by this.  Spring MVC typically uses session to isolate requests.  If two different users request the same thing, they are two different requests for the same thing.  I would suggest using some caching so that you are not hitting your DB every time, but other than that I see no problem.

Comment: By securing, I meant securing against "Billion Laughs attack" or any other attempts at XML injection. I will edit my question for more clarify.
Any tutorial on handling CSRF for SOAP requests?
How do I handle concurrent updates on the same resources? Or Reads when an another process is being updated.

Comment: In your explanation it doesn't sound like you are processing any XML, simply storing request/response pairs.  Unless you are parsing the XML it's simply a text document. If you are parsing it (or it's being parsed externally) I believe the common way to guard against it is to limit the number of bytes that can be expanded. How you do this would depend on what XML parser you used.

Comment: As for CSRF prevention this looks promising:  http://java.dzone.com/articles/preventing-csrf-java-web-apps

Comment: Finally, for concurrent modifications I would suggest having a lock mechanism in place such that the only one person can modify at one time.  If that is not satisfactory, then you might want to make it such that the user modifies a copy, then the copy is merged in.  The other option would be to have 2-way synchronization, but I think that would be really hard to get right.

Comment: With regards to your first commen regarding the XML response, I am thinking of using JAXB parser.

Comment: I took a peek at the JavaEE5 JAXB implementation JavaDoc but didn't see any direct way to turn off local expansion or limit the size of it, but that is where you want to look.  Beyond that I cannot give you specifics as I have not had much experience with JAXB.  Or, might I suggest you setup a little test to see if perhaps the JEE implementation of JAXB already handles it?